# Angular 8 @viewChild - returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

**pay.service.ts**

```
  @ViewChild('cardElementForm', { static: false }) cardElementForm: ElementRef;
  stripe = Stripe(environment.stripe.pubKey);

  async createStripeForm() {
    const stripeElements = this.stripe.elements();
    const cardElement = stripeElements.create('card');
    cardElement.mount(this.cardElementForm.nativeElement);
  }
```

Edit: added more code. This is my service that im importing into my page.ts

**page.html**

```
 <form #saveCard="ngForm" class="saveCardForm">
              <ion-item>
                <div id="cardElementForm" #cardElementForm></div>
                <ion-text *ngIf="error">{{ error }}</ion-text>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-text (click)="this.payments.createStripeForm()">Create form</ion-text>
              </ion-item>
              <ion-item>
                <ion-text (click)="this.payments.saveCard()">Send data</ion-text>
              </ion-item>
            </form>
```

**page.ts**

```
import { Pay } from '../services/pay.service';
```

I get error:

```
TypeError: this.cardElementForm is undefined
```

Wheres the problem? Im stuck at this.

Comment: can you provide us a stackblitz with a example of code :) ?

Comment: Avoid using `*ngIf` when using Element Reference. This might cause issues

Comment: Please add some more .ts code

Comment: just one second. im integrating stripe, i ll edit my post withing 10 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `@ViewChild('cardElementForm', { static: false })` from your service since your service doesn't have the template reference, so you don't have access to the `#cardElementForm` through out your service. What you can do is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('cardElementForm', { static: false }) cardElementForm: ElementRef;

  constructor(private payService: PayService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.payService.cardElementForm = this.cardElementForm;
  }
}
```

And your service has an attribute `cardElementForm: ElementRef;`

Comment: I've still problem with this. Added into my page.ts @viewchild and to my service i added: `export class PaymentsService {

  stripe = Stripe(environment.stripe.pubKey);
  public cardElementForm: ElementRef<any>;` the same problem :(

Comment: OK, i know what goin on. Thank you for you reply. The problem is mi DOM elements isn ready (im waiting to firebase auth to get uid, then i rendering my template, so theres no dom element.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling the method `createStripeForm()` in `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.